# css color condition in html based on database

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I used here bootstrap. I want to red mark those row which Activity contains "N" .In my database Activity field has two characters. they are Y & N. I also used here jquery data table.What can i do?

```
<?php
  while($reg_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sql2))
         {
         ?>
        <tr class="success">                 
            <td > <?php echo $reg_data['ID'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Name'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Email'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Type'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Dept'] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Activity'] ?> </td> // based on this field //////

         </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One best quick and easy way to do is to give an inline style:

```
<td style="background-color: <?php echo ($reg_data['Activity'] == "Y") ? "green": "red" ?>;">
  <?php echo $reg_data['Activity'] ?>
</td>
```

You might want to add `!important` just in case if needs an overriding:

```
<td style="background-color: <?php echo ($reg_data['Activity'] == "Y") ? "green": "red" ?> !important;">
```

> **Note:** I know inline styles are bad.

---

**Update:** Sorry I missed that you need to do it on the row. You can just apply the same thing on the `<tr>` instead of that `<td>`. So your code will be:

```
<tr class="success" style="background-color: <?php echo ($reg_data['Activity'] == "Y") ? "green": "red" ?>;">                 
    <td > <?php echo $reg_data['ID'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Name'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Email'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Type'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Dept'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $reg_data['Activity'] ?> </td>
 </tr>
```

Thanks to [Darren Sweeney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973552/darren-sweeney) for pointing it out.

Comment: This is not correct, op says: `I want to red mark those row` - this colors the cell, not the row - `I want to red mark those row` could be misinterpreted tho I suppose...

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Lemme check again.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Updated and given credits to you boss! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Check for `window.onload`.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Set a class based on activity on the desired `<td>` then upon window.onload use jQuery .parent() function and add css to the parent of `<td>` which containes "Y" as a class.

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('.YClassName').parent().css('background', 'YOURCOLOR');
};
```

Comment: Won't it be too overkill instead of using a simple CSS?

Comment: I answered based on the fact the he wants the color on `<tr>` not on `<td>`!!

Comment: @PraveenKumar if that is not the case then yes! just for color on td it is an overkill!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be creating a CSS class and adding it to the  element if your condition is met.

```
.red {
 background-color: red;
}

.green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

And then

```
<tr class="success <?php echo ($reg_data['Activity'] == "Y") ? "green": "red" ?>">

//table data

</tr>
```

As a sidenote, it'd be better to use "1" and "0" instead of "Y" and "N". Integer table-row types tend to perform better? At least, that's what I've believed until now.

Comment: Agree with you on `1` and `2`... `:)`